# how to asynchronously update viewmodel property based on selection of another property

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, mvvm

Say I have some kind of list control in the view from which I select a name and this sets a 'SelectedName' property in the viewmodel.  When a name is selected I then want to asynchronously fetch a set of data associated with that name and set another property with that data which will then update another control in the view bound to that other data property.

Can't use async/await with properties so can't make the request and assignment in the 'SelectedName' setter.

What is MVVM best practice for this case?

I was thinking maybe the selection of name could also trigger execution of a command (RelayAsyncCommand) in the viewmodel which could do the async fetch and assignment work. But is there any guarantee that the 'SelectedName', which would be needed by the command, would be updated before the command executes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As with any asynchronous UI, the first thing you need to think about is what the additional states are going to look like. Specifically, you now have a "Loading" state, and it's a good time to also think about your "Error" state.

I developed a type that is described in [my MSDN article on async data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx), which acts kind of like a data-bindable `Task<T>`. Using that type, you can do something like this:

```
public string SelectedName
{
  get { return _selectedName; }
  set
  {
    _selectedName = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
    SelectedNameDetails = new NotifyTaskCompletion<SelectedNameData>(FetchNameDataAsync());
  }
}

public NotifyTaskCompletion<SelectedNameData> SelectedNameDetails
{
  get { return _selectedNameDetails; }
  set { _selectedNameDetails = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Then you can data-bind to `SelectedNameDetails.Result` to display the details when they load; and `SelectedNameDetails.IsNotCompleted`, `SelectedNameDetails.IsSuccessfullyCompleted`, and `SelectedNameDetails.IsFaulted` to switch between Loading, Success, and Error view states.

Comment: Yes! Read your article last weekend and promptly forgot all about it. Great point about always remembering to handle all relevant states.

Comment: hello @Stephen Cleary, I saw your article and i've been trying to follow. It throws an nonexisting error when I use Onpropertychanged. I'm trying to update another property after a property with a NotifyTaskCompleted is loaded with data. Having a tough time atm.

Comment: @gdubs: It's difficult to tell what the problem is. Could you post your own question, complete with example code?

Comment: @Stephen Cleary Apologies for the late response. Just found the time. Here's the jist of what it looks like. I'm not getting the error anymore, but I still can't figure out how to properly update another variable after the data returns from the api call. here's a fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/OWoTq2 (won't run, but just shows the calls i'm making)

Comment: @gdubs You can't access `NotifyTask<T>.Result` until the task is completed; until then, it's `null`. The easiest solution for you is probably to create a separate `async` method that awaits `NotifyTask<T>.Task` and then sets `Clients`.

Comment: @StephenCleary awesome, that seems to have worked. Won't that lock the loading of UI? Not sure how to test if it does.

Comment: Not if you're using `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can't do async stuff directly within the `SelectedName` setter, you can still call an `async void` method from within the setter that does all the async logic and sets the second property. The only disadvantage is that this method can not notify the `SelectedName` setter when it is done (since it has to be `void`), but that should not be necessay in your case?